# MATLAB: Splitting a matrix based on multiple values

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm dealing with matrices of this format:

```
M =
1    1    3
1    1    1
1    2    2
1    2    1
1    2    2
2    1    5
2    1    1
2    2    3
2    2    4
2    2    2
...
```

What I want to do is extract sub matrices where the values in the first and second column can be grouped such that:

```
M1 =
1    1    3
1    1    1

M2 =
1    2    2
1    2    1
1    2    2

M3 =
2    1    5
2    1    1

...
```

I have been trying to think hard about how to index the matrix for this and I have a matrix available:

```
I =
1    1
1    2
2    1
2    2
...
```

that I could use for indexing. I was wondering if I could use it but I'm not 100% sure how. I don't want to use a `for` loop since the matrixes can be rather large and the order of complexity can become very large.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What do you mean by "sub matrices where the values in the first and second matrix are the same"? M1 != M2

Comment: Sorry, mistype, I will correct it.

Comment: Is you input data already sorted in a way that your sub matrices are connected blocks in the original matrix? Will you end up with many sub matrices or is just the large input data your problem?

Comment: Will your second column values always change even when the first column values do not change and not change when the first column values do change? I mean.. can you simply tell from the second column when to take your submatrices?

Comment: Daniel, yeah. The are connected blocks, the smallest block will be the first block.
Matthias, yeah you can tell from the second column when they will change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easily done with [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
M = [ 1    1    3
      1    1    1
      1    2    2
      1    2    1
      1    2    2
      2    1    5
      2    1    1
      2    2    3
      2    2    4
      2    2    2 ]; %// data
[~, ~, u] = unique(M(:,1:2), 'rows'); %// unique labels of rows based on columns 1 and 2
M_split = accumarray(u(:), (1:size(M,1)).', [], @(x){M(sort(x),:)}); %'// group rows 
                                                                     % // based on labels
```

This gives a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) containing the partial matrices. In your example,

```
M_split{1} =
     1     1     3
     1     1     1
M_split{2} =
     1     2     2
     1     2     1
     1     2     2
M_split{3} =
     2     1     5
     2     1     1
M_split{4} =
     2     2     3
     2     2     4
     2     2     2
```

Comment: @MatthiasW. Thanks! Solutions with `accumarray` usually are :-)

Comment: You can also use `findgroups` in place of unique to find groups in the matrix. `u = findgroups(M(:,1),M(:,2));` and the rest will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect for what I want!